# Voltage and load in a circuit

Tags: current, sata

Can anyone explain to me how current/load works in a circuit, please?

Example: four SATA HDDs connected in series via single cable.

Each HDD draws 12 V @ 2 A during the start. Does that mean that there is 8 A current via the first HDD connector?

4th hdd 2A <
3rd hdd 4A <
2nd hdd 6A <
1st hdd 8A <
PSU

Or is it just 2 A across the whole cable?

Comment: They're actually electrically connected in parallel...

Comment: That would explain it because officially SATA power connector can handle only 4.5A (shared across three pins).

Comment: If splitter is used and there is 2x 4 hdds on same cable - it would melt cable I guess no?

Comment: @DavidHajes The 8A current doesn't go through pins. 8A comes in through the wire, 2A goes to the hard drive through the pins, 6A keeps going through the wire to the next connector.

Comment: You might want to configure staggered spin-up - this will reduce your peak current. Might be a BIOS setting

Comment: Worth noting the question isn't really how it works in "a circuit" but more specifically how it works in SATA power cables in a computer

Comment: @user253751 wire is soldered directly to pins. That is why I wonder. If I understand all right, current is only drawn where needed. Stagering in BIOS is not possible on SATA drives, SAS only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a schematic where resistors represent the drives. They are actually connected in parallel, not series. If each drive draws 2 A, then the total load is cumulative and will be 8 A. The cable will have differing amounts of current depending on which node you are measuring.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fI7Jwh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For more information, see [What are “Series” and “Parallel” Circuits?](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-5/what-are-series-and-parallel-circuits/)

Comment: Thanks JY. But the cable.and 1st connector is still loaded with  8A. It makes me wonder why first connector survives...it is just for 10sec though.

Comment: @DavidHajes As you stated, the 2 A draw is only during startup. Time and duration are important factors as well in determining current-handling capability. Also many systems offset or stagger the startup of hard drives so that they do not all draw high current at the same time. While the connector on the PSU side may be only rated for 4.5 A, it will survive brief over-current conditions.

Comment: Yep, standard load is around 0.5A for both 5 & 12 V rails. PSU side connector is rated for 7A and max 75W

Comment: Sadly, consumer SATA controllers do not offer spin-up stagering. All drives start at once. Only solution would be delay timer per cable or even better per drive

Comment: Also the nameplate current draw for some devices can be a very pessimistic worst case scenario number.

Comment: @vir yep, that is why I rather do "field" tests. HDD stickers says max 12/5V @ 0.75A. In reality, 12V @ 1.9A & 5V @ 0.45A. I have seen kids hooking up 5-6 HDDs per cable